# I lost current head branch in git

Tags: git, head

When I switch from Develop branch to a previously submitted, the head branch is my current branch,but the branch is not shown in my branch list 
(CMD: git branch).

When I finished some work,I don't be careful switch directly to Develop branches,oh my God，I lost these changes, how can I find just the part of change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move HEAD back to a previous location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location)

Comment: Please phrase your question in a more clear way. Its not clear what you  did

Comment: I solved the problem（git reflog      git checkout HEAD@{...} ）

Comment: I can't make good use of stackoverflow, I will study hard.In addition, I must learn English well.Now, I can only rely on translation software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the reflog to find out what happened and then recover to that point

---

#### [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

You can always use the `reflog` as well.
`git reflog`  will display any change which updated the `HEAD` and checking out the desired reflog entry will set the `HEAD` back to this commit.

**Every time the HEAD is modified there will be a new entry in the `reflog`**

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

[image]

---

### ***`How to find and restore added content (even if it was not commited )`***

Use the `git fsck` to find out about all the lose object (dangling) and then you can check them out with the `git cat-file -p <sha-1>` and restore them.

Comment: Who is down-voting all the answers? they are correct both of them

Comment: I am also very confused.

Comment: Even I am confused by the downvote as the answers are correct. Upvoting as I believe they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reflog` to identify where your working copy was previously.  Once you've identified the relevant commit, you can just do `git checkout <commit>` to get back to it.

Comment: Or `git reset <commit>` to reset the branch to what `HEAD` was before being "lost" ? OP's a bit unclear imho

Comment: @GregoryPakosz - That would reset `develop`, which probably isn't what's wanted.  It's most likely that the OP will want/need to create a separate branch pointing at that commit.

Answer (score 0):

git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}

Thank you all.